# Multistage dockerfile skips parts/stages [Nodejs & Python]

Tags: reactjs, flask, dockerfile, skip, docker-multi-stage-build

I have a project which consists of a React website (frontend) and a python script on a flask server (backend).
My folder structure looks like this:

`.
--backend
--frontend
--Dockerfile`

The content of my multi-staged Dockerfile is:

`FROM node:14-slim as frontend
WORKDIR /app/frontend
COPY frontend/package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY frontend .
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 3000
FROM python:3.9.5-slim-buster as backend
WORKDIR /app/backend
COPY backend .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["python", "server.py"]`

Now here's the weird part:

When I run `docker build -t myname .` to build the docker-image the first part (nodejs) of the Dockerfile won't be executed. It starts with python, which means the whole nodejs part is missing and nothing of that will be copied. And I get no error messages.

Now when I switch the stages in the Dockerfile to start with python and secondly with nodejs, both will be executed, but the container won't work.

Has anybody an idea why the first stage will not be executed? I'm at my wits end :/

I'm using a windows 10 machine with docker desktop to build my images/container.

Thanks in advance!